# c# calling process "cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#

I'm a c# newbie so bear with me. I'm trying to call "pslist" from PsTools from a c# app, but I keep getting "The system cannot find the file specified". I thought I read somewhere on google that the exe should be in c:\windows\system32, so I tried that, still nothing. Even trying the full path to c:\windows\system32\PsList.exe is not working. I can open other things like notepad or regedit. Any ideas?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PsList.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ECC0-70AA

 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32

04/27/2010  11:04 AM           231,288 PsList.exe
               1 File(s)        231,288 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   8,425,492,480 bytes free
```

```
    try
    {
        // Start the child process.
        Process p = new Process();
        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //This works
        //p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\regedit.EXE";

        //This doesn't
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\PsList.exe";
        p.Start();

        // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
        // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
        p.WaitForExit();
        // Read the output stream first and then wait.
        s1 = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred :{0},{1}",
        ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: did you run your Visual Studio under Administrator account? It could be something going on with user permissions. You can disable UAC on Windows just for testing too.

Comment: @Junior: UAC cannot cause a FileNotFound.

Comment: Are you running 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this in the first place unless you *really* need to.

Instead, use the [`Process` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0).
You can get all of the currently executing processes by calling [`Process.GetProcesses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=net-6.0)

To get the memory use of a single process, check the [`WorkingSet64` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64?view=net-6.0) of the `Process`  object.
To get the CPU usage of a single process, [use Performance Counters](https://web.archive.org/web/20151009013543/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bclteam/archive/2006/06/06/619284.aspx).

Comment: Thanx for the quick responses!

Yes I am running 64-bit windows (windows server 2003)

I'm trying to use the output of PsList.exe with some arguments to get some CPU/memory information. but the first step was to just get PsList.exe to execute.

I am now using the full path to the original location of PsList.exe (not in system32) and it is suddenly working.

Is there a way to have the application look in the PATH variable so I don't have to specify the full path?

Comment: You should use the .Net library instead; it will be much faster, simpler, and more reliable.  Call `Process.GetProcesses`, then loop through the `Process` objects.  For CPU usage, [use Performance Counters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/06/06/619284.aspx).

Comment: @laura: I don't know how's windows 2003 behavior, but on Vista, depending on what you're trying to do with Process class (like accessing modules) you could have an permission issue. You could try it as Slaks said: foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses()) { /* do something with p variable */}

Comment: Nice, here's a list of Performance Counter classes I think will work on Windows 2003 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392738(v=VS.85).aspx